# How to override abstract generic method with concrete return type?

Tags: java, generics

How do I create an abstract method that is generic, but is implemented to return a concrete type?

Consider this simple abstract class:

```
public abstract class Master {

    public abstract <T> T getValue();

}
```

Each of the subclasses of `Master` should implement the `getValue()` method, but return a concrete type:

```
public class DateSlave extends Master {

    @Override
    public LocalDate getValue() {

        return LocalDate.now();
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class ListSlave extends Master {

    @Override
    public List<String> getValue() {

        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

I assume I am doing the whole generics thing wrong as I'm not very well-versed in their usage. The above subclasses offer this warning: `Unchecked overriding: return type requires unchecked conversion. Found 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>', required 'T'`.

Is there a better way to create an abstract method that the subclasses must implement, while also providing their own concrete return type?

Comment: If you have a `Master` reference and you call the method, how do you know which type will be returned? Why is only the method generic and not the class? i.e. Why not `Master<T>` and subsequently `StringList extends Master<List<String>>`?

Comment: You can have `Master#getValue()` simply return `Object`. That's essentially what you're doing anyway, and you can always make the return type more specific in a subclass. Either that, or make `Master` generic (i.e. declare the type parameter on the class instead of the method).

Comment: `public abstract <T> T getValue()` can only safely return null. Its return type is whatever the call site requires it to be; so `Integer a = aMaster.getValue();` and `String s = aMaster.getValue();` are both legal; but the implementation of `getValue()` has no information as to what return type is required. Hence, only null is safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
public abstract class Master<T> {

    public abstract T getValue();

}

public class DateSlave extends Master<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate getValue() {

        return LocalDate.now();
    }
}

public class ListSlave extends Master<List<String>> {

    @Override
    public List<String> getValue() {

        return new ArrayList<String>();
    }
}
```

`Master<T>` is a generic class. The return type is declared on each concrete class.